# Links text browser: Add starter URL on "Go to URL"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, browser, links

In Links text browser running in terminal, how to add starter URL when pressing `g`?

Pressing `g` will show `Go to URL` form. The form is blank. Lets say I want a starter URL `http://www.mywebsite.com/recent/post/` to save time when browsing

Comment: It sounds like you were hoping for specifically a feature `links` just doesn't have, which is a "homepage" that you can access with a single button, while links will still open up by default to a blank page.  While this just isn't within the scope of what `links` does, I have included a method as an answer that should give you the closest thing possible.  If it's something you only sometimes want to happen, it may be worth picking an alias other than "links" to differentiate it from the default vanilla behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `alias links='links http://www.mywebsite.com/recent/post'` into your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc.  `links` takes a url on the command line just like most any other browser does, and will open it rather than a blank page if it's included.  Adding an alias for it will save you time typing it if this is a regular thing.